# LinearGradient with multiple stops

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am having an idea about drawing a `LinearGradient` with only **2 colors** but with **3 stops**, i.e. 2 colors on the 2 sides but the neutral is not in the middle, it can be left or right (stops between 0 -> 1).

I know **stops** needs to be the same length as **colors** from [flutter site](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html).

> The stops list, if specified, must have the same length as colors.

My idea is create a combined color and add to middle of **colors**, now im able to use **3 stops**. But color transition look not smooth as i expected. Below is my code.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Custom stops')),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [colorLeft, Color.alphaBlend(colorLeft, colorRight), colorRight],
            stops: [0, 0.7, 1],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Is there any other way to do it. The result should look like this but with smoother color transitions. I appreciate any helpful ideas, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try lerp example https://dartpad.dev/?id=4916732360a976a5e4cb33a915a64c86

```
colors: [colorLeft, Color.lerp(colorLeft, colorRight,0.25)??colorLeft, colorRight],
```

Adjust settings to suit your need. Read at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/lerp.html

Comment: @Dev ,Can you help me out in Stack Chart in flutter

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil see https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/stacked.html

Comment: @Dev, I already check this, I want to put my json data to this chart,

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Put a new question  with codes that you have already written and refer that question here

Comment: @Dev, see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71951405/put-json-data-in-flutter-stacked-chart)